# Generate TLS Certs using fabric-ca-server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ca, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am searching for a way to generate `TLS certs` for nodes using a `fabric-ca-server`. I am using `fabric-ca-client`. I have used `cryptogen` tool to generate the TLS certs to get something like this.

> tls
>
> ├── ca.crt
>
> ├── server.crt
>
> └── server.key

Running the command

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 -M ./OrgMSP --enrollment.profile 
tls
```

generates directory as shown below

> msp
>
> ├── admincerts
>
> ├── cacerts
>
> ├── keystore
>
> ├── signcerts
>
> └── tlscacerts

but cannot seem to get the `TLS certs`. So, is there a way to get these certs using the same `fabric-ca` service? If so, what options to provide while using the `fabric-ca-client`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: Can you post your crypto-config.yaml configuration and also certificate authority and peer configuration? This would help

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference bw two you can copy the file inside the cacerts and rename it to ca.crt, file keystore to  server.key and file in side the signcerts to server.crt and create the exact structure like generated by the cryptogen.

Comment: Thanks Arun. So, I am trying to enable TLS in an existing network. I have used the same set of certificates (as mentioned) to configure TLS. I have also updated the channel configuration (both for user and system channels) by adding the tls_root_certs value. Somehow the TLS handshake still fails. Can you tell if this is the right way to do it or if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @ghost94 you can check your certificate if they are tls certificate or not form the link below https://certlogik.com/decoder/. They should have the following section. 
 X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication (The one under signcert folder)